# How to model multiple topology classes in one query with ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, enterprise-geodatabase, oracle-spatial, st-geometry

We have a lot of geographic data with different geometry type in our application, which are persisted in the Oracle 11g database with ST_Geometry supported by Arcgis SDE 10.

The features can be organized with a tree structure:

```
Geographic Data(shape,name,address)
    ImportantFeature(level,classcode....)
        ImportFeaturePoint
        ImportFeatureLine
        ImportFeaturePolygon

    River
            RiverLine
            RiverPolygon

    Hotel:
        HotelPoint
    School
        SchoolPoint
    ...
        ...
```

And the origin data are created by Esri FileGeotadabase(.gdb), one feature one table(in arcmap), and then these data are exported to Oracle 11g by SDE.

Now we have database tables:

```
BuildingPoint
RiverLine
RiverPolygon
.....
```

And we need to query these data by different criteria, for example, we need to query all the geographic data, all the `ImportantFeature` data or all the `River` no matter the geometry type is point,polyline or polygon.

So I create view to make the features together like:

```
create view xxView as
    select shape,name,address from ImportFeaturePoint
union all
    select shape,name,address from ImportFeatureLine
.....
```

However I got a very low performance for this solution, check [my last post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/139664/spatial-query-by-esri-st-geometry-take-too-long), so I wonder if there is an alternative way to implement my requirement?

Comment: It's not that you got poor performance that was the problem, but that using multiple topology classes with duplicate rowids in a single view is forbidden by ArcGIS.  This question needs to be about a fundamental design change to your data model.

Comment: So which is more important? the `multiple topology classes` or the `duplicate rowids`?

Comment: And I just tried to search on the concrete table instead of the view, it also take a long time

Comment: It's not a matter of which is more important -- **both** are forbidden. Query time for a spatial search of a small subset of a 20k row table should be <10ms, but improper configuration has no bearing on this question.